# How make method in GUI running in background

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I want to create LAN chat app with UDP as a method to transfer an information. Here, I have some problem with my app.I have 2 essential GUIs. They are General GUI and Private chat GUI. In general GUI there is a JList which displays online users (users who are playing my app). and in Private chat GUI, I have a JText which displays chat history.

My problem is, how to make a method which runs continuously, so that I can update Jlist to inform list of online users and Jtext to inform every chat which came and sent back.

Comment: `Thread` is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JGroups, does exactly what you want, and I think they also have a sample chat application.

http://www.jgroups.org/

Comment: Not so sure it's extending a thread but... yea, it seems like he could use it :)

Comment: I just imagine, how  convert it to GUI. I already make it in simple way in CMD. I need to convert continuously thread from simple example to GUI. Thanks.